# Linq Recursive Search

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, iqueryable

In my program, I have objects that I will call "items". These items have a category parent, and it is possible for these parents to have category parents of their own. Therefore, to search these items by their category parents, I'm looking to recursively look through each parent and see if they contain my search string.

These objects are stored in a database. Each item has a name, some other irrelevant stuff, and a parent. The database is made into an IQueryable list, and calls the recursive method. However, I'm just not familiar enough with recursion to be able to complete this, so if anyone could lend me a hand, that would be great.

This is what I have:

```
class node
{
    private Category parent { get; set; }

    node (Item item)
    {
        this.parent = item.Category;
    }

    node (Category category)
    {
        this.parent = category.CategoryParent;
    }
}
class CategoryParentIterator
{
    public static node Search (node currentNode, string search) 
    {
        if (currentNode == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        //TODO: RECURSIVE PARENT SEARCH
        return currentNode; 
    }

    public static IQueryable<Item> Search (this IQueryable<Item> values, string search)
    {
        //TODO: SEARCH
    }
}
```

The search will be called by something like "List = List.Search(searchString)".

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://jasonrowe.com/2009/09/19/recursive-linq-query-example/

Comment: Note also you cannot have an extension Method in a non static class

Answer (score 1):

I think you should redefine your class.

let's have a unique class

```
public class Node
{
  public Node Parent { get; private set; }

  //additional properties etc...
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int Value {get; set;}

  public Node(Node parent)
  {
    Parent = parent;
  }
}
```

so now any Node instance has a parent property, if it is null then there is no parent and you reached the root.

So now the search logic:

```
public static T SearchInHierarchy<T>(T node, Func<T,bool> predicate)
{
  if(predicate) return node;
  if(node.Parent == null) return null; //null if not found
  return SearchInHierarchy(node.Parent, match);
}
```

Here the predicate is what the search you want.
An example:

```
public static Test()
{
  var ancestor= new Node();
  var parent = new Node(ancestor);
  var child = new Node(parent);
  var result = SearchInHierarchy(child, x => x.Name == "Foo");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found another solution that did not require recursion though.

Comment: @JoeFromAccounting Can you share your solution as answer?